# Master Page reloads every Time

Tags: asp.net

I use a Master Page in website. In master page I create a menu by accordion pane and repeater,this master page is base of all the other pages.
When user clicks on the items of Menu its sub items are open and when the user clicks on the subitem then the page navigates according to the url 
My problem is that,when the target page loads, master page is again loading and the menu binds again ,I do not want to reload menu at that time.
I think I should use the concept Of Nesting Master Page,but I am not sure it solves my Problem...

How can I do this

Comment: Of course the master page loads again; it loads on every page load when the page in questions defines that master page. Nesting master pages won't change that. What is your problem here?

Comment: when I click the subitems of items of menu,For ex when i click the  4th items its sub items are open, and when i click the 2nd subitems the page it targets is open, but when that page is open menu is again bind,so at the target page the menu is not in the previous state,it again comes back into its default state

Comment: Why don't you want the menu to bind again?

Comment: @riktiktik I think what he really wants is the Accordion to have the "correct" tab expanded for the current page, but it is reloading in its default state.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Well I think it would be better to address that issue instead

Comment: @riktiktik andrew is right,and i think there is surely someway by which i can stop the rebind menu when it is showing same thing again and again

Comment: @Vish The best way to go about it is to tell us why you don't want the menu to rebind over and over. You NEED to bind the menu when you go to another page otherwise the menu won't show up in the page at all.

Comment: @ rikitikitik When the menu bind again the its previous state is lost

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have your menu binding code in the Page_Load event of your master page. Place the code you use to bind your menu inside

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
//your menu binding here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is really where the problem lies

Comment: I want My menu is not Bind again for the pages which come under master pages,By using if(!IsPostBack) also the menu is bind again and again for all pages

Comment: @Vish If you fail to bind your menu on other pages, you *won't have a menu at all*.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Well, rereading his question, it would load, but what I suggested won't help him in any bit.

Comment: Can this senerio help me-If i Take a master page at the top level in which i kept menu,and the other master page which use that master page, and my pages are derived from that second master page, and by using some way my top level master page is load only one time,and other time only the second level master pages are bind

Comment: @Vish All your master pages will load everytime. If you suppress the menu binding in some way when you call a new page, the menu will not show up at all.

Comment: So,What Is the solution for that,I dont want my menu to bind again and again when it is showing the same thing......

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update panel concept with Contentpage

E.g.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlContentPage" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This isn't terribly helpful. It suggests a completely different path, but doesn't really attempt to flesh out how

Comment: its call ur Menu Method but its not updated. means its always open as same as status. Else u can prevent bind menu base on if condition menu is already bind not bind again.